# Transmission web UI and ERROR 405

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf

I have `transmission-daemon` listening on port `9091`. This is proxied by a `virtualhost` site in `apache2` using `ssl`.

I managed to get through the infamous `ERROR 409` due to my a missing `/` in the last part of the proxied address. Now I am facing however an `ERROR 405: Method now Allowed`.

This is the `virtualhost` configuration file I am using:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.bar.zaz
    ServerAlias bar.zaz
    ErrorLog /var/www/bar.zaz/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/bar.zaz/requests.log combined
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9091/web/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9091/web/

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bar.zaz/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bar.zaz/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bar.zaz/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The web UI loads fine and then I get the error, locking me out and avoiding me to use it.

Any Idea what am I missing?

Comment: Vhost is ok. Post full httpd config. Turn developer mode in browser to determine which request gets 405.